# Firebase: INVALID_TOKEN: Failed to validate MAC

Tags: firebase, google-oauth, angular, firebase-authentication, ionic2

I get this error when trying to authenticate via Google using custom JWT tokens generated with Flask-restful and firebase-token-generator-python library. In short:

`ref.authWithCustomToken(authData)`

Error message:

`INVALID_TOKEN: Failed to validate MAC.`

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.2 / Ionic 2. The app is being tested on an android device using [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) (with necessary credentials in Google Developer Console). I have recently enabled Cross-domain requests on nginx server. I can't find any documentation related to this error on Firebase or SO.

Any ideas?

Comment: I was getting this error. Turns out I had an typo in my code and the secret wasn't getting passed like I thought it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was sending an Authentication Token to Firebase formatted as a JSON string via `authData.toString()` including delimiters and quotes. This must have thrown the `Failed to validate MAC` error, whatever that means.

Comment: MAC in this context stands for [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). It means that the the contents of the authentication token were not properly signed. One way to get the error is indeed to wrongly encode the token.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when using the incorrect key. I was using the `apiKey` provided right on the homepage in the Firebase Console while I should have been using the database secret key given at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT/settings/database.

Comment: This is what the problem was for me.  Thanks!